# How to properly use the value_input_option for Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

How do I use the batch_update correctly?
Here is the relevant code:

```
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

val = ['99', '0', '0', '0', '0', '98', '98', '0', '0', '105', '0', '0', '105', '106', '99', '102', '105', '99', '100', '0']
uwss = client.open(bot.idToExcelName(0)).worksheet("UW")
rangeval = "B4:U4"
uwss.batch_update([{'range': f"{rangeval}",'values': [val]}],value_input_option: "ValueInputOption.user_entered") #Here is the question
```

After reviewing the documentation, I still cannot understand how to properly set the value_input_option to user_entered.
Here is a snippet of the relevant doc: [batch_update documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJnnT.png)
Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: do you get error message? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: don't put documentation as image - we can't select text from image to use it in answer or comment

Comment: you have to use `=` instead of `:` in `value_input_option="ValueInputOption.user_entered"`

Comment: `ValueInputOption.user_entered` is probably a constant or an enum defined in `ValueInputOption`. You should not quote it, but instead use it directly: `value_input_option: ValueInputOption.user_entered`

Answer (score 0):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
uwss.batch_update([{'range': f"{rangeval}",'values': [val]}],value_input_option: "ValueInputOption.user_entered") #Here is the question
```

#### To:

```
uwss.batch_update([{'range': f"{rangeval}", 'values': [val]}], value_input_option=gspread.utils.ValueInputOption.user_entered)
```

or

```
uwss.batch_update([{'range': f"{rangeval}", 'values': [val]}], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- By this modification, the value of `val` is put from cell "B4" of "UW" sheet.
- I think that `'range': f"{rangeval}"` can be also modified to `'range': rangeval`.
- It seems that `gspread.utils.ValueInputOption.user_entered` returns `USER_ENTERED`.

#### Reference:

- [batch_update(data, **kwargs) of classgspread.worksheet.Worksheet](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.12.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.batch_update)

Comment: Thats exactly it! Thanks mate!

Comment: @Diogo Silva About `Thats exactly it! Thanks mate!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer